# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\int_0^T|\Delta_n(t) -W(t)|^2dt = 0?$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

When studying Shreve's Volume 2, Chapter $4$ Stochastic Calculus, the author provided the following example $4.3.2$:

> We compute $\int_0^T W(t)dW(t)$ where $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion. Choose a large integer $n$ and approximate the integrand $\Delta(t)= W(t)$ by the simple process 
>   $$ \Delta_n(t)=  
> \begin{cases}
> W(0)=0  & \quad \text{if} \quad 0\leq t\leq \frac{T}{n}, \\
> W\left(\frac{T}{n}\right)=0  & \quad \text{if} \quad \frac{T}{n}\leq t\leq \frac{2T}{n}, \\
> \vdots \\
> W\left( \frac{(n-1)T}{n} \right) & \quad \text{if}\quad \frac{(n-1)T}{n} \leq t\le T
> \end{cases}.
> $$
>   Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\int_0^T|\Delta_n(t) -W(t)|^2dt = 0.$

I have trouble getting the last equality $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\int_0^T|\Delta_n(t) -W(t)|^2dt = 0.$

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Try Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @user658409 Use Fubini's Theorem twice? To interchange limit and expectation and limit and integral?

Comment: Just expectation and integral. Convert it to a limit of numbers. Should be maybe a bit tricky but doable.

Comment: Can you show its steps as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

For almost all $\omega \in \Omega$ the Brownian motion $\{W_t; 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ is uniformly continuous (since B.M. is continuous and we are on a bounded interval [0,T]). Fix $\omega$ and let $\epsilon>0.$ Then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|t-s|< \delta$ implies $|W(\omega,t)-W(\omega,s)|<\epsilon.$ Take $n_0 > \frac{T}{\delta}.$ Then $\forall n \geq n_0,$ we have that for all $t \in [0,T],$ $|\Delta_n(\omega,t)-W(\omega,t)|< \epsilon.$ Therefore,
$$\int^T_0 |\Delta_n(\omega,t)-W(\omega,t)|^2 dt \leq \epsilon^2 \int^T_0  dt=\epsilon^2 T.$$ This means that
$$\int^T_0 |\Delta_n(\omega,t)-W(\omega,t)|^2 dt \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$
And by the dominated convergence theorem
$$E \int^T_0 |\Delta_n(\omega,t)-W(\omega,t)|^2 dt \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Aren't $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E \int_0^T|\Delta_n(t)-\Delta(t)|^2 dt =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E \int_0^T|\Delta_n(t)-W(t)|^2 dt $ as $\Delta(t)=W(t)?$

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is direct from Eq (4.3.2). This equation is a well known theorem that says: Let $\Delta(t)$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E \int_0^T |\Delta(t)|^2 dt < \infty,$ then there exists a simple process $\Delta_n(t)$ such that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E \int_0^T |\Delta(t) - \Delta_n(t)|^2 dt =0.$

Comment: May I have a reference to this theorem?

Comment: Xuerong Mao, "Stochastic and differential equations", page 20, lemma 5.6. Also Capinski: page 82 and Oksendal: pages 27-28.

Comment: @Idonknow: I edited my answer to try to give a specific solution for the problem without using previous results.